# How can I go to my router's IP address from Firefox on Android?

Tags: firefox, firefox-android

Entering

> https://192.168.0.1/

In the navigation bar on my recently updated Firefox mobile (Android) always sends me to the default search engine. The previous situation was annoying enough (requiring the leading http(s)://) but now I literally have no idea how to just go to a IP-only web site.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding a bookmark (to the current page), and then editing the name and location of the bookmark to be what I wanted.

Then I can go to the bookmark. Stupid, but at least it is a work around.